# Plotting order within a faceted dotchart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a faceted dotchart in ggplot2 but cannot get the within-facet
categories to appear in the order that I want. The code for plotting the dotchart is:

```
g <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=Y, y=label)) + geom_point() 
g <- g + facet_grid(incentive ~ .,   scale="free")
g <- g + geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = Y + se, xmin = Y - se))  
g <- g + geom_vline(xintercept=1/6, linetype=2, colour="red") 
g <- g + opts(title="% Subjects Choosing Non-Focal Image",
          strip.text.y = theme_text()
          ) + xlab("%") + ylab("Groups")
print(g)
```

The problem with the plot is that within the "Money only" facet, the 1 cent and 5 cent categories are in the wrong order. The problem does not seem to be the order of the factors themselves, as:

```
> levels(df2$label)
[1] "0"      "1"      "1 cent" "5 cent" "6"     
>
```

[image]

**Update**: ordering the factor does not appear to change the plot order, i.e., plotting with label3 where:

> df2$label3
>      [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faH0b.png) 0      1      1 cent 5 cent 6
>      Levels: 0 < 1 < 1 cent < 5 cent < 6

```
>str(df2$label3)
Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "0"<"1"<"1 cent"<..: 1 2 3 4 5
```

The actual data frame:

```
df2 <- structure(list(Y = c(0.0869565217391304, 0.148148148148148, 0.172413793103448, 
0.384615384615385, 0.5625), group = c(0L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 6L), se = c(0.0856368459098186, 
0.079039229753282, 0.0762650540661762, 0.0805448741815074, 0.0726021684593052
), nudged = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), incentive = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Default behavior", "Imbalance only", 
"Money only", "Money & Imbalance together"), class = "factor"), 
label = structure(1:5, .Label = c("0", "1", "1 cent", "5 cent", 
"6"), class = "factor"), plot_order = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)), .Names = c("Y", 
"group", "se", "nudged", "incentive", "label", "plot_order"), 
row.names = c("as.factor(group)0", 
"as.factor(group)1", "as.factor(group)5", "as.factor(group)3", 
"as.factor(group)6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Aren't they in order already?  Remember that the y axis goes has the smallest value at the bottom.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that the `facet_grid` is plotting the *incentive-types* ('Default Behavior', etc) in an order that is conflicting with the order of the *incentive-value* (0, 1 cent, 5 cent, etc), which is why you are not getting the ordering you want within the Money Only group. The simplest way to fix it is to re-order your `incentive` factor, so that the Default Behavior is plotted at the *bottom* rather than the *top*:

```
df2$incentive <- ordered( df2$incentive,
                 levels = rev(c("Default behavior", "Imbalance only", 
                                "Money only", "Money & Imbalance together")))
```

and leave the rest of the code as-is. Then you get this plot:
[image]

Comment: To generalize this solution, if the column (say `df2$incentive`) is in the order you want it to be in (top to bottom), then `df2$incentive <- ordered(df2$incentive, levels = rev(unique(df2$incentive)))` will save you having to type the factor levels in the right order. (When I found this question I had 38 factors, each one a scientific name.)

Answer (score 0):

That sounds and looks really strange (as the labels are sorted by the order of factor levels, as @Dirk Eddelbuettel also wrote above), but you could always use [scale_discrete](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/scale_discrete.html).

I have made up a little example based on your code, but that looks also strange a bit, see:

```
g <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=Y, y=label)) + geom_point()
# add manual scale
g <- g+ scale_y_discrete(limits=c("0","1","1 cent","5 cent","6"))
g <- g + facet_grid(incentive ~ .,   scale="free")
g <- g + geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = Y + se, xmin = Y - se))  
g <- g + geom_vline(xintercept=1/6, linetype=2, colour="red") 
g <- g + opts(title="% Subjects Choosing Non-Focal Image",
      strip.text.y = theme_text()
      ) + xlab("%") + ylab("Groups")
```

[image: ggplot example plot]