# Facet plot ordered by expression

Tags: r

I have a melted data frame like this:

```
> head(Merged_Columns.m)
   SYMBOL Cond   logCPM variable     value
1   Baz2b    T 9.723115       0h  40.56290
2 Ccdc111    T 3.460456       0h   6.00879
3  Zfp456    T 4.809024       0h   2.22136
4   Itga8    T 4.633377       0h   4.69537
5    Tpm4    T 8.384930       0h  44.85390
6   H2-K1    T 9.333838       0h 218.91800
>
```

My plot code is

```
ggplot(Merged_Columns.m, aes(variable, value, colour=Cond))  + geom_point() +
facet_wrap(~SYMBOL,ncol = 2)
```

However I want to sort the plot so that the `SYMBOLS` get plottet ordered by the highest to the lowest `logCPM`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plotting order in ggplot is usually determined by the ordering of levels in the factor that you are using. Other questions show you how this is the case e.g. [Plotting order within a faceted dotchart in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774804/plotting-order-within-a-faceted-dotchart-in-ggplot2?rq=1)

In your particular case, you need to order `SYMBOL` by `logCPM`. I will show how you can achieve this using your small sample:

```
txt <- "SYMBOL Cond   logCPM variable     value
1   Baz2b    T 9.723115       0h  40.56290
2 Ccdc111    T 3.460456       0h   6.00879
3  Zfp456    T 4.809024       0h   2.22136
4   Itga8    T 4.633377       0h   4.69537
5    Tpm4    T 8.384930       0h  44.85390
6   H2-K1    T 9.333838       0h 218.91800"

df <- read.table(text=txt)

df$SYMBOL
[1] Baz2b   Ccdc111 Zfp456  Itga8   Tpm4    H2-K1  
Levels: Baz2b Ccdc111 H2-K1 Itga8 Tpm4 Zfp456
```

You can see that the level ordering for the factor is probably the same as the ordering you are getting in your plot at the moment. To change this ordering by descending `logCPM`:

```
df$SYMBOL <- factor(df$SYMBOL, levels=df$SYMBOL[order(-df$logCPM)])
df$SYMBOL
[1] Baz2b   Ccdc111 Zfp456  Itga8   Tpm4    H2-K1  
Levels: Baz2b H2-K1 Tpm4 Zfp456 Itga8 Ccdc111
```

The levels are now ordered differently, and this should be reflected in the plot.

Comment: where did you get the x from? x$SYMBOL

Comment: @BioMan my bad, that was a typo! It should be fine now.